# Get Attachments from Sharepoint Online ListItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am trying to get Attachments from a SharePoint Online ListItem or their URLs. So far I´ve found only solutions [like](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7fc86578-6502-433d-9ae1-b7e3ccde0209/get-attachment-url-in-sharepoint-online-office-365?forum=sharepointdevelopment) [these](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/48dfa040-fbff-4a0b-b974-711e20a5e6d8/how-to-check-whether-list-item-contains-attachment-or-not-using-client-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious).

But the problem is that when I browse the folder where the attachments should be, it is empty.

It is very confusing because in SharePoint Client Browser, the folder is not empty.

Also where should be stored `https://scundp.sharepoint.com/sites/list_overview_test/f0/Lists/Testlist2/Attachments/2/Dokument1.png` if not in the folder with url `https://scundp.sharepoint.com/sites/list_overview_test/f0/Lists/Testlist2/Attachments/2`?

In my code I am trying to write the ListItem's Attachment URLs to `newListItem["AFiles"]`. `listItem["Attachments"].ToString() == "True"` works correctly, so the block is only run if there are any Attachments.
However `bool h` is set to `false` and the folder is also interpreted as empty.

The SharePoint Add-in that I am working on has these Permissions:

- Web - manage,
- Site Collection - fullControl.

The whole Site Collection has the "Open Document in the client application" setting active.

```cpp
if (listItem["Attachments"].ToString() == "True")
{
    bool h = listItem.AttachmentFiles.AreItemsAvailable;

    try
    {
        Web oWeb = context.Web;

        Folder folder = oWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(
            siteName + "/Lists/" + listName + "/Attachments/" + listItem["ID"]);
        context.Load(folder);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        FileCollection attachments = folder.Files;
        context.Load(attachments);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        newListItem["AFiles"] = "";

        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile in folder.Files)
        {
            newListItem["AFiles"] = newListItem["AFiles"] + "  " +
                oFile.ServerRelativeUrl;
        }
    }
    catch (ServerException ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this task  using `WebRequest` in order to download files from sharepoint site:

```
public void DownloadFile(string serverFilePath, string destPath)
        {
            var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", ServerURL, serverFilePath);
            createDirectiory(Path.GetDirectoryName(destPath)); // this method creates your directory
            var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            using (var sReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                using (var sWriter = new StreamWriter(destPath))
                {
                    sWriter.Write(sReader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
```

if you wish to use the `Client-object-model` here are some good examples:
[How to get a file using SharePoint Client Object Model with only an absolute url at hand?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62087/how-to-get-a-file-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-with-only-an-absolute-url)

Comment: Yes, I can only use CSOM. Thank you I will try it, but will it work if I don't have the full Path.? I mean, in my code I get only the part of it up to the name of the file.